# Accessing Contact Name of a sent SMS using Telephony.SMS

Tags: android

I want to get simple information for my SMS inbox, namely the Name of the contact, and the body of the message.

I am able to get the body, but the contact name is blank.

Here is the code snippet

```
        String[] reqCols = new String[] { Telephony.Sms.Inbox._ID, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.PERSON, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.BODY };

        // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                new String[] { Telephony.Sms.Inbox.BODY, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.PERSON}, new int[] {
                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
        lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In my `listview`, I am able to get the Message body to show up, but not the contact name.

Note that if I use ".ADDRESS" instead, the contact number successfully shows up.

Any help? I do have "READ_CONTACTS" permission already.

EDIT: The only way I can think to get around this is to use ContactsContract.PhoneLookup and use the phone number to find the contact name. Seems like an necessary step that takes too long, though. No one has a better solution?